# Can I either input int or terminate scanf function?

Tags: c, scanf

Our task for school lesson is to input a number of integers. We don't know how many there will be.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to format `scanf` function that either stores integer or terminate itself by pressing enter.

Can I somehow put together `scanf("%d")` which only stores integers and `scanf("%[^\n])` which terminates `scanf` function?

What I have known yet is that I cannot use `scanf("%d%[^\n])` because `scanf` is waiting for that one integer, which I don't want to input because I already stored all integers I had to.

I don't really like a possibility to store string of all those integers into an array and then convert it to elements of another array with the exact numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @lurker You can't use `std::getline()` in **C**!

Comment: @lurker That is only for *nix systems. It is not known if the OP is using *nix.

Comment: As a general rule, whenever the question is "Can I do this <slightly clever thing> using `scanf`?", the answer is always "Perhaps, but it'd be much easier and more reliable to do it another way, *without* using `scanf`."  (I know, your textbooks and teachers have all given you the strong impression that `scanf` is *the* way to do input in C.  Unfortunately they all lied to you.  Real C programmers never use `scanf`, and they don't miss it.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Nor do they [each quiche](http://www.bernstein-plus-sons.com/RPDEQ.html).

Comment: But I don't want to discourage you.  Having the user type in some number of numbers, then indicate the end, is absolutely the right way to do it.  Most introductory C programs first prompt, explicitly, for the number of numbers, then try to input precisely that many numbers.  This is horrible from a UI perspective; it violates every human interface guideline in the book, but it's common precisely because it's so hard to do any better if `scanf` is the tool you're limiting yourself to.

Comment: @dbush I think you meant Nor do they [use Pascal](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html).

Comment: @SteveSummit Unfortunately we have no other option than to use [scanf] function in this task.

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys.

Answer (score 1):

Scan a character. Skip space and tab. Exit on newline.
Unget most recent character and try to scan an integer. If unable to scan an integer, scan and discard non-digit except space tab and newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    char i = '\0';
    int value = 0;
    int result = 0;

    printf ( "type number separated by space then enter\n");
    while ( 1 == scanf("%c",&i)) {//scan a character
        if ( ' ' == i || '\t' == i) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( i == '\n') {
            break;//newline so leave loop
        }
        ungetc ( i, stdin);//replace the character in input stream
        if ( 1 == ( result = scanf ( "%d", &value))) {
            printf ( " number entered as %d\n", value);
        }
        else {
            scanf ( "%*[^0-9 \t\n]");//clean non digits except space tab newline
            //or you could just break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the user hits enter first, or number-space-enter.

Comment: @user3121023 That´s what I wanted. I have to say that it is far more complicated than I expected it to be, but works. So I guess I will now go through it a few times to know exactly what each line does, maybe write it one more time so it isn´t 100% as yours and I will understand it better + add if function for a-z and A-Z case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function is difficult to use correctly.

Instead, read a line at a time with `fgets`.  If the entered string is just a newline, you exit the loop.  If not, use `strtol` to parse the value.  You'll know if just an integer was entered if the end pointer points to the newline at the end of the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100], *p;
    long val;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        // if enter was pressed by itself, quit loop
        if (!strcmp(line, "\n")) {
            break;
        }

        errno = 0;
        val = strtol(line, &p, 10);
        if (errno) {
            perror("error reading value");
        } else if ((p != line) && (*p == '\n')) {
            // a valid integer was read
            printf("read value %ld\n", val);
        } else {
            // a non-integer was read or extra characters were entered
            printf("not a valid integer: %s", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not allowed to use these. We can only use printf. But still thanks a lot for your feedback.